# CSS styled <li> mouseover that won't change on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a simple ul list.  the li's contain simple a href's.

I have a background and all that on the li and I want to change the li's border when the a href is mouseover...

Is that possible?
     `<ul>
         <li><a href="#" class="admin_button">Button 1</a></li>
      </ul>`

anyway, I need the li border to change on mouseover...  this seems simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the li the same size as the a tag.

then in your css file:

```
ul li {
    border: 1px solid #000000;/*Black 1px border*/
}

ul li:hover {
    border: 2px dotted #ff0000; /*Red 2 pix dotted line border*/
}
```